# Assign values of a stack to another stack

Tags: c++, copy, stack

I am working on this assignment.

I need to create a temporary stack without initializing it.

Then push the items of stack 1 into this temporary stack using a `while` loop.

Then I need to use another (nested?) loop to walk through the temp stack and add the items from temp stack onto stack 2.

Then I need to set stack 1 and 2 equal so stack 2 remains unchanged.

Comment: What is linkedStackType? And why can't you just copy? You're copying to tmpStack already.

Comment: I need to revise this question.

Comment: linkedstacktype is constructor

Comment: data was added to the stack previously

Comment: I need to copy the items to the temp stack. Then I need to create a loop that walks through the temp stack and adds the items to stack 2. That's the assignment. In the book I see where it says how to copy a stack. But this is not what I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interfaces look a bit off. Let's start there and see if that gets you over your hump.

`stack.top()` usually peeks at an item, but doesn't remove it. This doesn't seem useful for transfering from one stack to anther. You already have isEmptyStack() to check that the top element exists.

`stack.pop()` usually takes the top item from a stack. This sounds useful for transferring.

`stack.push(item)` places item onto the top of the stack. This sounds useful for transferring.

`stack.push()` just seems wrong. Push what?

Hopefully, once you implement these methods, the rest will start to make sense from the english description of the problem you provided.

Update: this is what you want:

```
|a  |   |     |   |   |     |   |   |     |   |c  |
|b  |   |     |b  |   |     |   |b  |     |   |b  |
|c  |   |     |c  |a  |     |c  |a  |     |   |a  |
1   tmp 2     1   tmp 2     1   tmp 2     1   tmp 2

|   |   |     |   |   |     |   |   |a
|   |b  |     |   |   |b    |   |   |b
|   |a  |c    |   |a  |c    |   |   |c
1   tmp 2     1   tmp 2     1   tmp 2
```

Now, with just push, pop, and IsEmptyStack, with no assigning of stacks to one another (that sort of defeats the purpose of the assignment), can you do this?

Comment: template <class Type>
void transferStack(linkedStackType<Type>& stack1,
                   linkedStackType<Type>& stack2)
{
 Type item;
   linkedStackType<Type> tmpStack = stack1; 
 
   
   while (stack1.isEmptyStack() == false)
   {
      item = stack1.top();
      stack1.push(item);
   }
    
   tmpStack = stack1;
while (stack1.isEmptyStack() == false)
{
 item = stack1.top();
 stack2.push(item);
}
stack1 = stack2;

Comment: @OurFamilyPage: You don't. Feel free to update your question with the code posting, perhaps with an "Updated: ..." line to explain.

Comment: @OurFamilyPage: does top() remove the top item or just peek at it? if it just peeks, your code in the comment will infinite loop. If it removes the top item, why not call it pop(), which is something every programmer learns when dealing with stacks?

Comment: top() peeks at it, pop() removes it.

Comment: That is very helpful! Let me go back and change it.

Comment: Yes the while loop is infinite.

Comment: to push an item you just use plain old push? It will just start at the top?

Comment: First, pop() probably returns the item, so you can use item=stack.pop() instead of having one line for top and one line for pop. Second, why are you assigning one stack to another? What does the statement "stack1=tmpStack" accomplish? If you took out that line, what would the lines mean to you? This also includes the initialization line at the very top of your function. No assignment of stacks to other stacks is allowed. You want three stacks. Keep them separate and just move the items between them.

Comment: Oh no. I better fix that too.